# Kubernetes cannot access grafana and prometheus fron Google cloud platform

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grafana, prometheus

I have followed this [link](https://github.com/bakins/minikube-prometheus-demo) to install Grafana/Prometheus in Google cloud kubernetes. I hope it is deployed successfully please find the following response for reference,

**Service Created successfully :**

```
kubectl --namespace=monitoring get services
NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
grafana      NodePort   10.27.249.8     <none>        3000:32703/TCP   1h
prometheus   NodePort   10.27.249.233   <none>        9090:31939/TCP   1h
```

**Namespace created successfully :**

```
kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    19h
kube-public   Active    19h
kube-system   Active    19h
monitoring    Active    1h
```

**PODS response :**

```
kubectl --namespace=monitoring get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-1323121529-8614m      1/1       Running            0          1h
node-exporter-lw8cr           0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   17         1h
node-exporter-nv85s           0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   17         1h
node-exporter-r2rfl           0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   17         1h
prometheus-3259208887-x2zjc   1/1       Running            0          1h
```

Now i am trying to expose the external-Ip for Grafana but i couldn't keep on getting following exception "Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "prometheus" already exists"

```
kubectl --namespace=monitoring expose deployment/prometheus --type=LoadBalancer

Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "prometheus" already exists
```

**Edited**

> ```
> kubectl -n monitoring edit service prometheus
>
> Edit cancelled, no changes made.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already deployed the Prometheus service manifest file in the monitoring namespace. However, you are trying to deploy a service with the same name at the same namespace.That's not acceptable As Two Service cannot co-exist in the same namespace with same name.

**Solutions for your problem**

I would use the following command to edit the already deployed Service.

```
kubectl -n monitoring edit service prometheus
```

Then your favourite text editor would pop up, you just need to update 
**type: LoadBalancer**

Basically, your service will be edited.

**Edited**

If you are not able to use the above command, then you do following steps :
you need to edit the Prometheus service manifest file and update it with **type: LoadBalancer**.

Now you need to **apply** `kubectl apply -f prometheus-service.yaml`

Comment: I used the above comment and edited the file but it says "Edit cancelled". Also After editing the file do i need to restart the service ? The Load balancer will expose the external IP right ?

Comment: Basically, if you can update the **type : LoadBalancer** It will create an external IP on the Network Loadbacalncer (For instance ELB on Amazon etc). I have edited the answer as well

Comment: But I couldn’t save this file ...I’m using google cloud

Comment: you need to edit the service manifest file. check Updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159266/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-velnaga).

Comment: could you please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: yea sure:) we can do live debugging. lets fix the time

Comment: I am fine with anytime ...tonight or this weekend. I am absolutely fine.

Comment: The weekend would be perfect.

Comment: Ok ..then I’ll ping you on Saturday if you free means we can do a live debugging...thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I am free in the whole daytime :) Just ping me when you are here

Comment: Shall we discuss in a chat ?

Comment: Yea sure Lets start the chat

Comment: I couldn't see any chat options here

Comment: I am also New to chat here. I think we need to create it.

Comment: Are you able to see any options ?